# Best version if Ubuntu for Lenovo B50-70

Tags: lenovo, versions

I have a Lenovo B50-70 laptop with 1T HDD, 4gig Ram. Hoping to find the right release/version of Ubuntu. Long on Unix, short (zero) on Ubuntu experience, please be gentle. Any advice would be an advantage.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd go for Xubuntu 16.04.